# freeradius Segmentation fault

Tags: freeradius

I am using freeradius server on ubuntu 11.10. when i run

```
radtest username password 127.0.0.1 100 testing123 "
```

command. in server side then i got :

```
rad_recv: Access-Request packet from host 127.0.0.1 port 38006, id=243, length=60
    User-Name = "username"
    User-Password = "password"
    NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
    NAS-Port = 100
# Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
+- entering group authorize {...}
++[preprocess] returns ok
Segmentation fault
```

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the program. Have you considered filing a bug?

Comment: i get "radclient: no response from server for ID 177 socket 3 "

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when I started working on freeradius. I didn't found any solution or cause of this Segmentation fault.

I reinstalled Freeradius from repository ubuntu 12.04 and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

These basic transient SEGFAULTs are usually caused by ABI mismatches where an older version of the server library is loaded by a newer version of radiusd.

Since version 3.x.x the server will verify magic numbers in it's various libraries to check that they're all from the same version of the server, and refuse to start if they are not.